# How can I use two iAd views in the same view to switch back and forth?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iad

I want to have the `iAd` banner switch randomly between the top and bottom of the screen each fill, but I can't seem to get two `iAd` banner views to work. I can't even get the `iAd` to appear at the top of the screen.

How would I change the position of the `iAd` banner?
How would I make them swap at fill time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change the position of the ad banner, just set it's frame. Let's say you want to move it to the top of the screen, you would do:
`myAdBanner.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, myAdBanner.frame.size.width, myAdBanner.frame.size.height);`.

In order to find out when an ad is loaded, conform to [ADBannerViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/Reference/ADBannerViewDelegate_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/ADBannerViewDelegate). Then, set the view controller as the delegate (`myAdBanner.delegate = self;`). When `-bannerViewDidLoadAd:` is called, you know an ad was filled, and you can switch the position of the ad banner.